# removing first and last name on customer/account

Tags: magento2, php

[image]I need to figure out how to remove displaying the customers first and last name on the customer/account page. I have figured out how to do this with the checkout process already.

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly from where you want to remove? Can you please share screen shot?

Comment: @ZealousWeb - its the Default Billing Address and Default Shipping Address locations  on xxx.xxx/customer/account page when you first goto it beneath the address book title

Comment: @ZealousWeb - added to original post. Please assist. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have added answer. Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my magento it was like this - https://prnt.sc/yop6an

To remove first name and last name from my account , you should change the html address template

For that please go to admin panel and go to below path

```
Stores > COnfiguration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Address Templates
```

Edit **Html** template and remove two variables {{{var firstname}} and {{{var lastname}} from template. After removing these variables updated template will be like below.

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br />
{{var country}}<br />
{{depend telephone}}T: <a href="tel:{{var telephone}}">{{var telephone}}</a>{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br />F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br />VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

Output will be like - https://prnt.sc/yop5eq

Comment: Could you please upvote this? @lostnconfused